# Locust load test a "not secure" site

Tags: python, locust

I would like to test a site with APIs that at this stage of development is classified as "not secure".
In the Locust documentation is said that:

> Safe mode:
> The HTTP client is configured to run in safe_mode. What this does is that any request that fails due to a connection error, timeout, or similar will not raise an exception, but rather return an empty dummy Response object. The request will be reported as a failure in User’s statistics. The returned dummy Response’s content attribute will be set to None, and its status_code will be 0.

I would like to know if there is a configuration that let you disable this option.

Thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean by "I would like to know if there is a configuration that let you disable this option."?  What would you like the request to respond?

Comment: Are you trying to use locust on a HTTP service that you haven't added TLS to yet or a non-HTTP service?

Comment: @itprorh66 I would like to use a "safe-mode=false" in the conftest.py

Comment: @Jeremy I haven't added TLS yet

Comment: I believe locust by default does not validate SSL, but the documentation is unclear. The [request method](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=httpuser#locust.clients.HttpSession.request) appears not to check by default. However, [`FastHttpUser`](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/increase-performance.html#locust.contrib.fasthttp.FastHttpUser) is clearly documented to not validate SSL by default as you can see from the `insecure= True` constructor default arg.

Comment: It seems that `FastHttpUser` with a few tweaks let me achieve the result I was looking for.
I will also research further if `HttpUser` has a "insecure" option.

Thank you very much @Jeremy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`safe_mode` has nothing to do with SSL/TLS, it refers to `requests` not throwing an exception when the request fails (for whatever reason).

To make HttpUser/requests ignore SSL issues, add `verify=False` to your call.

——

You're looking at a very old Locust documentation, right? I dont think the text you mention has been there for quite a while.

`safe_mode` has been removed from `requests` (it used to look like this https://github.com/psf/requests/pull/604) but the same behaviour is implemented by Locust here https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/51b1d5038a2be6e2823b2576c4436f2ff9f7c7c2/locust/clients.py#L195

Comment: thank you for your answer,
I'm using a docker container with a custom locust image derived from the latest locustio/locust image.
Despite this when I use 'HttpUser' and catch the response, I get the dummy content '0' cited in my question before.

Comment: Can you try adding verify=False to your method call?

Comment: After adding `verify=False` to the `client.get/post` , it worked.
Thank you

Comment: Please, edit your answer in order to complete, so I can mark it as solved

Comment: Done! We might want to make that the default in Locust in the future. (I thought it already was)